# Retrieving NTLM hash

Tags: c++, c, windows

How do I retrieve the NTLM hash of the current logged in user? Do I have to inject into lsass.exe? If so, what is the process for obtaining the hashes? Sorry if this is a duplicate but I couldn't find what steps to take after injecting into lsass.exe.

Comment: You could look into the source code of mimikatz, for example, it does just that

Comment: I wasn't aware of that; Thank you.